# How to read from Iso file?

Tags: linux, iso

> **Duplicate of**
>   https://superuser.com/questions/171795/how-to-read-from-iso-file

Are there any linux command which lets me to read Iso file byte by byte without mounting?

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do?

```
dd if=/path/to/your/isofile.iso bs=1 | whateverotherprogram
```

That would read the file byte by byte and pipe the result to another program, whatever that might be.

Comment: dd if=/mnt/disk5.iso | ugur    It didn't work.

Comment: Did you put also the bs=1 parameter?

Comment: i did. What does bs parameter means

Comment: bs means Block Size, and in this case it would have been one byte. Oh well.